# How is Santiago, Chile, during Easter?

Tags: chile, public-holidays, events, santiago-de-chile

What should I expect in that period? Will the usual tourist attractions and shops be open between Holy Friday - Easter Sunday? Is there some kind of public tradition / procession that I could participate in as a tourist?

According to [This is Chile](https://www.thisischile.cl/semana-santa-easter-celebrations-in-chile/?lang=en):

> The capital empties out over the long weekend. Typically traffic-clogged streets turn quiet, the air is clear and this bustling metropolis becomes peaceful – making it the perfect time to get out and explore the city.

But they mostly mention visiting churches and participating in masses.

Comment: Sorry we didn't have an answer from you. Hope you can share your experience for future travelers.

Comment: Hey @ZachLipton, I appreciate the bounty! Sure, I'll add an answer describing how it was  a bit later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent Good Friday - Easter in Santiago. Good Friday is already a holiday in Chile.

All the malls, restaurants, museums and the cable car were functioning normally even on Sunday, I only couldn't find any single opened currency exchange. [Bus from/to the airport](http://www.centropuerto.cl/) was operating as in any other day too.

If you want to go out of the city (Valparaiso, Viña del Mar), you have to buy your ticket some time in advance - as I confirmed with some locals, pretty much everyone spends the holiday there, so tickets to come back to Santiago on Sunday may be difficult to get (you can buy them on-line before though). I only thought about it on Saturday and didn't manage to get one.

I didn't find any Easter-specific events, but in every square I went to there was something happening anyway. Plaza de Armas was the most interesting I think, there was some national dance competition happening there, I think it's a weekly event but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. There was also dancing in Plaza de Armas on a non-Easter Sunday in February when I was there, though I'm not sure it was specifically a competition.